# index vector by value in R

Tags: r

Say I have two character vectors

```
vec <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') 
pat <- c('D', 'B', 'A')
```

how do I get the indexes of the occurrences in `vec` of the values in `pat` in the order they appear in `pat`?

I can try

```
which(vec %in% pat)
```

but this gives me them in the incorrect order: `1 2 4`. I want them as `4 2 1`.

Comment: Try `match(pat, vec)`

Comment: Searching for the man for `help("%in%")` returns the man for `match`.

Comment: `%in%` is also documented on that help page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried different ways to solve this problem before and always found that the easiest way to solve it is the solution as mentioned in @DavidArenburg's comment:

```
match(pat, vec)
# [1] 4 2 1
```